# t syntax to use near 'GROUP BY bids.item' at line 1 in

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here is my query:

```
SELECT   bids.item, 
         bids.username, 
         bids.amount, 
         orders.product, 
         orders.status, 
         products.enddate 
FROM     bids, 
         orders, 
         products 
WHERE    bids.username=? 
AND      Now() > products.enddate 
AND      orders.status=0 
ORDER BY bids.amount DESC 
GROUP BY bids.item
```

> **Warning**:  PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax
>   error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY bids.item' at line 1 in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\auction\application\model\UsersModel.php** on
>   line **250**

Edit, Rizier thank you for editing my post, is there a thread to teach me how to make that layout or do I have to do it manaually?

Comment: http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm <- For formatting SQL :D

Comment: @Rizier123 much needed link for most of the new comers

Comment: Your query is probably not going to do what you want, because you don't have proper `join` conditions.  Learn to use (and then *always* use) explicit `join` syntax.

Comment: Also learn about grouping. Why do you think you need a `group by` at all? You aren't aggregating anything in your select list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Order by` should come after `group by`

```
WHERE bids.username=? AND NOW() > products.enddate AND orders.status=0 
GROUP BY bids.item
ORDER BY bids.amount DESC
```

Also change the comma separated old style of join to proper `inner join` syntax. It is more readable. For more info on `INNER JOIN` check [***here***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Comment: Aha. Thank you very much. TIL.

Comment: Maybe you want to include some reference to proper select syntax e.g. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Answer (score 0):

GROUP BY should be before ORDER BY clause like:

```
SELECT bids.item, bids.username, bids.amount, orders.product, orders.status, products.enddate 
FROM bids,orders,products 
WHERE bids.username=? 
AND NOW() > products.enddate 
AND orders.status=0 
GROUP BY bids.item
ORDER BY bids.amount DESC
```

A side note, implicit joins are discouraged and hence you should instead use joins explicitely like:

```
TABLE1 INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON ....
```